# Code Igniter subquery Active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, subquery

I'm going to use subquery in my model code igniter using this query

```
SELECT KTP, EMAIL, NAMA, PASSWORD, SALT, CONTENT, PERNR, ACTIVE
    FROM ref_user
    WHERE EMAIL = 'fahmi@gmail.com' AND PASSWORD = (SELECT SALT FROM ref_user WHERE EMAIL = 'fahmi@gmail.com') + 'mi'
```

In my CI i'm storing user input inside $param
i'm using salt to add security to my login

password = 'random generated salt value inside database' + 'user input password'
so i tried to do it using subquery to those in CI

```
function signin_user($param){
        $this->db->select('ktp,email,nama,password,salt,content,pernr,active');
        $this->db->from('ref_user');
        $this->db->where('email',$param['email']);
        $this->db->where('password',MD5("SELECT salt FROM ref_user WHERE email=$param['email']" . $param['pass']));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        return $query->row();
    }
```

Comment: Just a tip don't use MD5 for passwords any more unsafe, Use this to create http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php and this to verify http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: And what happened? Where there any errors?

Comment: it got syntax eror but, you already fix the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ONLY in response to your question and no comment as to the implementation etc...

Also, there are much better ways to do this, but I'll let the others comment on that.

Now I see you had attempted to use `echo $this->db->last_query();` but failed to see the big error PHP would have generated...

You have a mishap with your Select String and its not totally obvious the first time as it looks like it should work.

As email is surrounded by quotes in `$param['email']` it confuses things and you'll get a parse error.

```
$this->db->where('password', MD5(
    "SELECT salt FROM ref_user WHERE email=$param['email']" . $param['pass'])
     );
```

There are two solutions

Method 1: Help out PHP by indicating where your variable is by using {} to wrap your variable. So `$param['email']` becomes `{$param['email']}` like so...

```
$this->db->where('password', MD5(
    "SELECT salt FROM ref_user WHERE email={$param['email']}" . $param['pass'])
     );
```

Method 2: Go old school and use concatenation.

```
$this->db->where('password', MD5(
       "SELECT salt FROM ref_user WHERE email=" . $param['email'] . $param['pass'])
       );
```

Method 3: BAD: You could Ditch the single quotes - but I personally dislike this immensely, so lets not even go there as it promotes bad habits.

**UPDATE: The Better Way** Using CI Query Builder
CI allows you to create compiled selects... So you could do it like this..

```
public function signin_user($param) {
    //Precompile the Sub query
    $this->db->select('salt')->from('ref_user');
    $this->db->where('email', $param['email'] . $param['pass']);
    $sub_query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
//        echo $sub_query;
//        echo'<br>';
    $this->db->select('ktp,email,nama,password,salt,content,pernr,active');
    $this->db->from('ref_user');
    $this->db->where('email', $param['email']);
    $this->db->where('password', MD5($sub_query));

    $query = $this->db->get();
//        echo $this->db->last_query();

    return $query->row();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check are your getting value for `$param['email']` by `echo $param['email']; exit;` in your controller.

If so  Try this

```
$query_password = $this->db->get_where('ref_user', array('email' => $param['email']));
$val = $query_password->result_array();
$password = $val[0]['salt'];

function signin_user($param){
        $this->db->select('ktp,email,nama,password,salt,content,pernr,active');
        $this->db->from('ref_user');
        $this->db->where('email',$param['email']);
        $this->db->where('password', $password));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        //echo $this->db->last_query();
        return $query->row();
    }
```